# Meaning of affine transformation

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), I learned that an affine transformation between two vector spaces is a linear mapping followed by a translation.

But in a book [Multiple view geometry in computer vision](http://books.google.com/books?id=si3R3Pfa98QC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=An%20affine%20transformation%20%28or%20more%20simply%20an%20affinity%29%20is%20a%20non-singular%20linear%20%20transformation%20followed%20by%20a%20translation.%20It%20has%20the%20matrix%20representation&source=bl&ots=aQq-pv5c4L&sig=TlgCj-acH7Z19mo3u_09izuKsL8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JT72TqKODojh0QHkz73OAg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=An%20affine%20transformation%20%28or%20more%20simply%20an%20affinity%29%20is%20a%20non-singular%20linear%20%20transformation%20followed%20by%20a%20translation.%20It%20has%20the%20matrix%20representation&f=false)  by Hartley and Zisserman:

> An affine transformation (or more simply an affinity) is a
> **non-singular** linear  transformation followed by a translation.

I wonder if these are two different concepts, given that one does not require the linear transformation to be non-singular while the other does?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure they are different concepts (and by asking it the way you ask it you have answered your question yourself already)... The map that takes all to $0$ is an affine transformation in the Wikipedia sense while it isn't in the second sense.

Comment: You could think of it this way: an affine transformation in the sense of Wikipedia may or may not be an _bijective_ (or _invertible_) function. However the book reserves the term for the bijective ones. [As t.b. points out, the Wikipedia definition is strictly more general.]

Comment: An affine transformation preserves affine combinations, i.e. linear combinations in which the sum of the coefficients is $1$.  Those are precisely the ones whose value does not depend on which point in the space is chosen to be the origin.  If it's non-singular, then the image of a set of points will not have any affine relations not already present in the original set; otherwise it will.  (But as to whether one or the other definition is correct, I have no opinion right now.)

Comment: Thanks, people! @t.b.: Can affine transformation be defined between two vector spaces with different dimensions? If yes, is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Mathematical_Definition, with affine spaces replaced by vector spaces?

Comment: I think the definition of an affine transformation between two vector spaces is as follows. A map $f:V\to W$ is affine if there exists a $w$ in $W$ such that the map $v\mapsto f(v)-w$ is linear. In words, an affine transformation is a linear transformation up to a translation.